# Python PIL - Save to mimetype "image/jpeg", not "image/pjpeg"

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library, tweepy

I'm currently working with Tweepy in trying to update a profile picture. Tweepy supports up to three different mimetype formats, '**image/gif**', '**image/jpeg**', '**image/png**'.

Using PIL, I'm trying to convert the image to **'image/jpeg'**, though everytime I attempt to use PIL to conver the image it comes out as **'image/pjpeg'** instead. I've tried adding pjpeg to the allowed list on Tweepy but it doesn't understand how to handle it.

How can I convert an image with PIL to **'image/jpeg'**, and not **'image/pjpeg'** mimetype?

```
from PIL import Image
import mimetypes

pic = Image.open(rootDir + "pic.png")
pic = pic.convert("RGB")
pic.save(rootDir + "new.jpg", 'jpeg', progressive=False)

print mimetypes.guess_type(rootDir + "new.jpg")
```

Comment: Stop saving progressive JPEGs.

Comment: I've looked through the supported file formats for PIL. It doesn't state how to or how not to save as progressive. What do I have todo to not save them as progressive? https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/formats.html

Comment: ["The save method supports the following options: ... progressive

    If present, indicates that this image should be stored as a progressive JPEG file."](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-jpeg.htm)

Comment: Good find, but even after adding "progressive=False", I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: Files don't *have* MIME types, they are *mapped to* MIME types by some piece of software. `mimetypes.guess_type()` is, as its name implies, a *guess* and as such can be wrong. If `tweepy` is using `mimetypes.guess_type()` internally and rejecting valid images based on its erroneous result, that is a bug in `tweepy` and you should take it up with its developers, or submit a patch. Is the error coming from `tweepy` or from Twitter itself?

Comment: @kindall It's not a bug in tweepy, at least not exactly... it's a Windows specific issue actually, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are on Windows.

From digging through the `mimetypes` code, I found that the first time you call pretty much anything in the module, it will run `mimetypes.init()`, which sets up the available mime types.  On Windows, these are loaded out of the registry by default, which, at least on my machine, has 'image/pjpeg', the IE mimetype for jpegs, registered as well as 'image/jpeg', the mimetype everyone else uses.  Since `mimetypes` stores the mimetypes as a dict and loads the registry mimetypes as the `strict` versions, there's no way to avoid the mimetype being overwritten, and in fact, since I don't think order of retrieving registry values is defined in any way, it makes this indeterminate on Windows since the registry defines 2 mimetypes for the extension.  I don't see any way to do this that isn't ugly and hacky, but it looks to me like you should be able to make things work for you with this:

```
import mimetypes

# alternatively, you could just call this with
# files=file_path_list of mimetype files that you create
mimetypes.init()
mimetypes._default_mime_types()
mimetypes._db = mimetypes.MimeTypes()
```